# What exactly is a software push?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [CompTIA Network+ Certification All-in-One Exam Guide, 6th Edition (Exam N10-006) by Mike Meyers (2015)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071848223)

Example:

> You should also internally ask yourself some isolating questions, such as “Was that machine involved in the **software push** last night?” or “Didn’t a tech visit that machine this morning?” Note you will only be able to answer these questions if your documentation is up to date. Sometimes, isolating a problem may require you to check system and hardware logs (such as those stored by some routers and other network devices), so make sure you know how to do this.

What exactly is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means an update. New (additional or revised) code (or software) was pushed out to (updated on) the client machine.

Answer (score 2):

A software push could mean any of a number of specific things, but they all describe copying software code from a location or environment to a target location or environment. This could include at least the following:

- From a development environment to a code respository
- From a code repository to a test environment
- From a test environment to production
- From a staging environment to release distribution server
- From a distribution server to clients

Answer (score 1):

Usually computer code is maintained in a central repository to which developers "Push" code to.
The push here means that the developer has made changes to some code and needs to update the central repository so other developers can have recent code.The other developers can then take a "Pull".

In broad networking sense, a Software Push also might mean pushing files to an HTTP server